# unique_ptr destructor advantage

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

What is the advantage of using the using a unique_ptr destructor over just closing the file directly in C++11?

i.e. this code

```
FILE* p = fopen("filename","r");
unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)> h(p, fclose);
if (fclose(h.release()) == 0)
    p = nullptr;
```

vs.

```
FILE* p = fopen("filename","r");
fclose(p)
```

Comment: You just need: `{ std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, int(*)(std::FILE*)> h(std::fopen("filename", "r"), std::fclose); }`. That's it.

Comment: Yes, will work as long as I don't want to copy the unique_ptr if h were a member variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last two lines of the first code block are not needed.  Also, you're not doing anything with the file.  That's where the advantage becomes obvious.

With unique_ptr, you schedule the `fclose()` call once, when you open the file, and never worry about it again.

With C style, you have a lot of code in between `fopen()` and `fclose()` and have to make sure that none of that code can jump over the `fclose()`.

Here's a more realistic comparison:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)> smart_file;
smart_file h(fopen("filename", "r"), &fclose);
read_file_header(h.get());
if (header.invalid) return false;
return process_file(h.get());
```

vs

```
FILE* p = fopen("filename","r");
try {
   read_file_header(p);
}
catch (...) {
   fclose(p);
   throw;
}
if (header.invalid) {
    fclose(p);
    return false;
}
try {
    auto result = process_file(p);
    fclose(p);
    return result;
}
catch (...) {
   fclose(p);
   throw;
}
```

Jumping over the `fclose()` can take many forms: `return`, `if`, `break`, `continue`, `goto`, `throw`.  The C++ compiler handles all of them when you use a smart pointer.

Comment: The last two lines is to set the pointer to null. But I agree not strictly needed.

Comment: @Damian : But why would you do that anyway? Do you also set all your `int` variables to `0` before they go out of scope?

Comment: @ildjarn: Plus, `h.reset();` would have done the trick, except for the part about detecting a failure of `fclose()`.  I can't imagine what good knowing closing a file failed would do, though.